# For-In Loops multiple conditions in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

How to use `for` loop and add an array of my four string values. Please check below code:

```
let facilityID = FacilityID.map { "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",")
let charges_per_km = ServiceChargesPerKilomiter.map { "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",")
let charges_per_Minute = ServicChargesPerMinute.map { "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",")

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: NetworkRequest.hostpath+"save_service_request.php")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

var data: [[String: Any]] = []

for i in 0..<facilityName.count {
    let dataArray =
        [
            "facility_id": (facilityID),
            "facility_name": facilityName[i],
            "charges_per_km": (charges_per_km),
            "charges_per_minute": (charges_per_Minute),
        ]

    data.append(dataArray)
}
```

How do I add facilityID, Charges_per_km, and charges_per_Minute inside my `for` loop? I will already add facility_name in `for in` loop.

Can any one help me?

Comment: BTW, you may want to adopt standard naming conventions, specifically "camelCase" (starting your variables with lowercase letters, capitalizing first letter of every subsequent word, e.g. `serviceChargesPerKilometer` or `chargesPerKm`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing four separate arrays and want a single array of dictionaries, you don't need (nor want) those `map` statements. You can do the following:

```
var data = [[String: Any]]()

for i in 0 ..< facilityName.count {
    data.append([
        "facility_id": FacilityID[i],
        "facility_name": facilityName[i],
        "charges_per_km": ServiceChargesPerKilomiter[i],
        "charges_per_minute": ServicChargesPerMinute[i]
    ])
}
```

Or, if you needed them as strings:

```
var data = [[String: String]]()

for i in 0 ..< facilityName.count {
    data.append([
        "facility_id": "\(FacilityID[i])",
        "facility_name": facilityName[i],
        "charges_per_km": "\(ServiceChargesPerKilomiter[i])",
        "charges_per_minute": "\(ServicChargesPerMinute[i])"
    ])
}
```